# curl stays empty even if the url works

Tags: php

I'm just stuck with the curl thing...
It doesn't give me any problem before in my code but here, it appears when I do a var_dump, that the $EAACCOUNT is always empty... Nevertheless, I'm pretty sure that the url request is right because it works in other parts of my coding... 
Do you guys have any idea how I could solve this?

```
    $account= "http://www.ea.com/p/fut/a/" . $machine . "/l/". $ulocal ."/s/p/ut/game/fifa13/user/accountinfo?timestamp=". $time;
    $auth   = "http://www.ea.com/p/fut/a/" . $machine . "/l/". $ulocal ."/s/p/ut/auth";
    $quest  = "http://www.ea.com/p/fut/a/" . $machine . "/l/". $ulocal ."/s/p/ut/game/fifa13/phishing/validate";


    //Cookie Data includes the two keys from above
    $cookie_string = $EASW_KEY."; ".$EASF_SESS;
    //Setup cURL HTTP request
    $ch = curl_init($account);                                                                                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie_string);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded')                                                                   
    );                                                                                                                   

    $EAACCOUNT = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    //Get personaID and Platform
    $d = json_decode($EAACCOUNT, true);
$personaID = $d->userAccountInfo->personas[0]->personaId;
    $platform  = $d->userAccountInfo->personas[0]->userClubList[0]->platform;
```

Comment: Does [`curl_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) or `curl_errno` suggest anything?  Also see: [`curl_setopt's`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)CURLOPT_VERBOSE.  Otherwise always Wireshark.

Comment: `var_dump($EAACCOUNT)` before json_encode .... what do you get